# If the story and the names of Arslan are Persian, why is the theme Japanese?

Tags: arslan-senki

I am from Iran and I saw just a few episodes. This story was famous in my parents' childhood and I really wonder why it is so different from the original story (the author is called Naghibolmamaulek). And why is the theme completely different from Persia?

Comment: Because it is a fictional works. They are just borrowing name and story.

Comment: Thank you for your care.I wasnot sure how to spell the name in english for it has a sound not existed in english

Comment: And they could change the name of the story if they wanted to be inspired by

Answer (score 3):

The anime's based on [Hiromu Arakawa's manga of the same name](https://myanimelist.net/manga/51233/Arslan_Senki), which is, in turn, based on [Yoshiki Tanaka's fantasy novel series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Heroic_Legend_of_Arslan). As the Wikipedia page for the latter states, it appears to have taken inspiration from a few different sources:

> Whilst the protagonist's name (which is [Turkic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkic_languages) for lion) appears to may have been taken from the popular Persian epic of [Amir Arsalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amir_Arsalan), other than this anachronism, Arslan and his Parsian enemies and allies primarily share many parallels with [Cyrus the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_the_Great) and other historical figures of [6th century BCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6th_century_BC) [Persia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_Empire) (albeit with several liberties taken), whereas the conflicts with the Lusitanian forces (which bear the [Byzantine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Empire) [Orthodox cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodox_cross)) – despite mostly French names and a certain religious zealotry implying a connection to the ([Catholic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Church)) [Crusades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crusades) (again, with liberties taken)– appear to be based on the [Byzantine–Persian Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine%E2%80%93Sasanian_wars), specifically those of the [6th century CE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6th_century). Furthermore, several names of prominent Parsian characters appear to be taken from known important figures throughout [Persian history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Iran) as well as the historically unsubstantiated legendary parts of the historiographic Persian epic [Shahnameh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahnameh). Additionally, supernatural elements mostly based on [ancient Near East mythology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religions_of_the_ancient_Near_East) increasingly play a role as the series goes on.

I wasn't able to find any reference to Naghibolmamaulek, the author you mention, but the short answer to your question is: **the anime's based on a story that was *inspired* by the one your parents may have heard during their childhood, among others, and it is not a direct adaptation of it/them.** As such, Tanaka (and possibly Arakawa too) took some liberties and changed a few things around.

Comment: I'm guessing that "Naghibolmamaulek" is Mohammad Ali Naqib al-Mamalek the author of Amir Arsalan. It looks like it might be an alternate transliteration of the last part of the name.

Comment: Makes sense. Not sure how I missed it, given I looked for similar patterns in names, but there you go :P